# launcher (lh toolbar?) no-show in 13-10 installs

Tags: unity, launcher

in 13-04, my launcher failed to appear.  i tried dozens of suggested fixes and no joy.

i just installed 13-10 on this machine and get the same result (desktop but no launcher.

i had been using a xfx geforce 9800gt card.  removed it and re-installed.  still no launcher.  i have also used an evga gtx550T.  same result.

so the problem does not change with different graphics cards.

should i do a complete install with re-format?

i have not had this machine usable for over six months.

many thanks in advance.

dave mallery

Answer (score 1):

I first tried to preserve `/home` in the installation.  That failed.  Once I did a full install, formatting `/home`, the problem left.  perhaps some of the many things I did to my home directory screwed up unity.